# Material UI Tab loosing connection to Tabs when wrapped inside another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tabs, material-ui

The Material UI documentation has [the following example](https://material-ui.com/demos/tabs/#simple-tabs) of the Tabs and Tab components:

```
<Tabs value={value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
    <Tab label="Item One" />
    <Tab label="Item Two" />
    <Tab label="Item Three" href="#basic-tabs" />
</Tabs>
```

I want to create my own component that in turn creates the tab (so I can style it with `withStyles`). So I modified the code to this:

```
<Tabs value={value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
    {["one", "two", "three"].map(label => <MyTab label={label} />)}
</Tabs>
```

```
function MyTab({ label }) {
    return <Tab label={label} />;
}
```

However, this seems to break the connection between the Tab and the Tabs. The Tabs onChange event doesn't fire anymore. Adding a `value` property to the Tab does not help.

What am I doing wrong here? Is it impossible to wrap a Tab inside another component? If so, how am I supposed to be able to style the Tab?

Here is the complete code:

- [Original documentation example](https://codesandbox.io/s/749kz1lyjj)
- [My modification](https://codesandbox.io/s/zl50llv9op)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You mixed up value and label. You also have to pass value to Tabs.

Here is a working SimpleTabs component render function:

```
render() {
  const { classes } = this.props;
  const { value } = this.state;

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <AppBar position="static">
        <Tabs value={value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
          {["one", "two", "three"].map(label => (
            <MyTab key={label} value={label} label={label} />
          ))}
        </Tabs>
      </AppBar>
      {value === "one" && <TabContainer>Item One</TabContainer>}
      {value === "two" && <TabContainer>Item Two</TabContainer>}
      {value === "three" && <TabContainer>Item Three</TabContainer>}
    </div>
  );
}
```

And MyTab component:

```
function MyTab(props) {
  return <Tab {...props} />;
}
```

You should also consider setting default state.value in order to have a "default tab".

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I now realize that the `value` attribute must be on MyTab. Just having it on Tab will not help. Consider editing your answer to include that, because I think it's the key to getting this right. Again, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for +1. `value` attribute is both on MyTab and Tab component in my anwser. While applying it to Tab I am using spread operator since props are passed to MyTab in form of key, value pairs ([functional component](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html)). 
`<Tab {...props} />` equals `<MyTab key={props.key} value={props.value} label={props.label} />` ([spread operator in props](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#spread-attributes)).

Answer (score 0):

To have in mind. The solution isn't to pass the value prop. You are missing the connection because you are overriding the onChange function. The onChange function is a heritage from the Tabs component, so, when you are creating your component you could use:

```
function MyCustomComponent(props){
  return <Tab {..props}/>
}
```

or you could use:

```
function MyCustomComponent({value, label, onChange}){
  return <Tab label={label} value={value} onChange={onChange}/>
}
```

In other words, you are missing the connection between Tabs and Tab children because you are erasing the onChange function in the Tab children components.